# How I can hide controls, full screen buttons in Youtube Player android API?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to hide the buttons in a YouTube video player (api). I used

```
player.setShowFullscreenButton(false)
```

this hides the fullscreen button successfully, but I did not find way to hide the control button -- that button can go to YouTube application.

I tried using

```
player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
```

This hides all buttons, but also changes the progress bar, but I need the old progress bar.

Any help?

Answer (score 7):

You can initiate the player as a "[Chromeless](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle#Enums)" player. That should do it.

Comment: But I want all the controls of YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT Except "YouTube" Button. How to do this in Android. It's doable in iOS & Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

In your *onInitializationSuccess* method use this code

```
player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
```

> Full code

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {

        // loadVideo() will auto play video
        // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
        player.loadVideo(Config.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);

        // Hiding player controls
        player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
      //player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

**Note:-**

> **1. For showing all interactive controls**
>
> public static final YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle DEFAULT
>
> **2.For hiding all interactive controls**
>
> public static final YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle CHROMELESS
>
> **3.For showing only a time bar and play/pause controls**
>
> public static final YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle MINIMAL

For more visit official [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle#Enums)

Answer (score 0):

I only know this works with version 1.2.2 of Youtube player of the API. Hides YOUTUBE button only.

```
((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIDEO_PLAYER_ID)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0))
                .getChildAt(4)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(3)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: `ClassCastException: ProgressBar cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup`

Answer (score 0):

To disable only full screen

> setShowFullscreenButton(boolean show)

Shows or hides the fullscreen button on the player controls.

For Reference [See this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#setShowFullscreenButton(boolean))