# Enable/Disable youtube controls when video is fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

When Youtube video starts i disable controls with option controls=0.

When the youtube video is fullscreen, how can i set controls=1? I want display Youtube controls when the video is fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the player as this "[Chromeless](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle#Enums)" player.

> `public static final YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle CHROMELESS`
>
> A style that shows no interactive player controls.

This process was suggested in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255052).

Comment: My question is for javascript